# Comprobar siguiente registro MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente duda. En estos momentos tengo el siguiente código:

```php
$sql= "SELECT * 
       FROM banco 
       WHERE a = 'substr ($buffer, 0,   1) ' 
       AND  c = 'substr ($buffer, 1,    8)' 
       AND c = 'substr ($buffer, 10,    2)'";

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0)
{ 
   //aquí va el insert 
} else { 
   // que compruebe el siguiente registro 
}
```

En estos momentos estoy encallado y no consigo sacar cómo realizar que, si el `if` anterior es diferente de `0`, el `else` compruebe el siguiente registro.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

```php
if ()(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0)
```

Te sobran unos paréntesis en el `if`. Prueba con lo siguiente:

```php
$sql= "SELECT * FROM banco WHERE a = 'substr ($buffer, 0,   1)' AND  c = 'substr ($buffer, 1,  8)' AND c = 'substr ($buffer, 10,   2)'";

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0) { 
  //aquí va el insert 
}else { 
  // que compruebe el siguiente registro 
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola, los () los he puesto sin querer, el problema lo tengo en el ELSE que no tengo claro como revisar el siguiente resgistro.

Comment: Hola, no entiendo que quieres decir con el siguiente registro. Lo que escribas en el ELSE solo se va a ejecutar en caso de que la condición del IF no sea cierta, es decir, todos los casos en los que el número de filas resultante sea distinto de "0". Un saludo

Comment: Hola, te explico se la select realizada cumple con la clausula where y el valor que nos devuelve es 0 se realizara un insert, si no debe de mirar el siguiente registro de la tabla a ver si cumple la condicion o no.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que pretendes es recorrer el recordset debes usar un While y luego dentro del ciclo puedes poner una condición para preguntar si un registro tiene o no un valor y si lo tiene esto sino lo otro ej:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM banco WHERE a = 'substr ($buffer, 0,   1)' AND  c = 'substr ($buffer, 1,  8)' AND c = 'substr ($buffer, 10,   2)'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql); 
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   if($row['a']==0) {
  echo "Una cosa"; 
} else {
  echo "Otra cosa"; 
}
}
```